# updating each row with previous values plus current values

Tags: php, mysql

sorry for the complicated heading.i am doing learning php and got stuck.i have a database table `table_name`

```
id(primary key)     name       ip 
1                     a         192.168.0.1,192.168.0.5,171.87.65 //separated by comma's
2                     b         192.168.0.1,175.172.2.6,164.77.42
```

now i want to add an array of values ip[0] and ip[1] coming from a two different text-area to the end of the ip's of each name and just updating the ip column of each row.so it will just append new values with previous one.

```
name a<textarea rows="4" cols="40"  name="ip[]"></textarea> 
name b<textarea rows="4" cols="40"  name="ip[]"></textarea>
<input type="submit" />
```

this is how its inserted

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$ip_details = $_POST['ip'];
$values = array(

array('id' => '"1"', 'name' => '"a"',  ip => '"'.$ip_details[0].'"'),

  array('id' => '"2"','name' => '"b"', ip => '"'.$ip_details[1].'"'),
);


 $columns = implode(', ', array_keys($values[0]));
foreach($values as $value) {
    $value = implode(', ', $value);

$statement = "INSERT INTO `center_listt` (id,name,ip)  VALUES     ($value)";

    $res=mysql_query($statement);
echo "success";
}
}
```

i need to update each rows of `name`a and b with new values coming from text-area with previous values.
 i am thinking of array_push after fetching ip from table in while loop but could not really do it.`warning: array_push expects parameter 1 to be array integer given` its because the $row['ip'] fetched in while loop is not valid array which array_push expects.
and it will only add new values in different new rows each time which i don't want.can someone please help what to do.

Comment: This task is not advisable. It is time for a rethink. 1NF. Required reading: [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3653462/2943403)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {


//print_r($ips); die;
$i = 0;
foreach($_POST['ip_details'] as $ipaddr) {
    $ips[$i] = $ips[$i].$ipaddr;
    $i++;
}

$r = 1;
foreach($ips as $ip){
//echo "UPDATE center_listt SET ipdetails = '$ip' WHERE `id_center` = '$r'"; die;
    if(mysql_query("UPDATE center_listt SET ipdetails = '$ip' WHERE `id_center` = '$r'")) echo "IP Address Updated <br />";
    else echo 'error occurred';
    $r++;
}
}

$sql="select * from center_listt";
$res=mysql_query($sql);
if(!$res) {
die('could not connect'.mysql_error());
} 
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) 
{
echo $row['ipdetails']; }
?>
```

its a bad practise to insert form values from array.you can fetch it from db bcoz if in future you want to add new form values you need to rewrite again with array values while fetching from db will only need you to insert new values in db.

my query will add ip's in your specific column in a single row only updating the ip with new values.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
$values = array(...); // WARNING: escape `$ip_details` here!!
$to_insert = array();
foreach($values as $row) {
    $to_insert[] = "(".implode(", ",$row).")";
}
$statement = "insert into `center_listt` (`id`, `name`, `ip`)
              values ".implode(", ",$to_insert)."
              ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `ip`=concat(`ip`,',',values(`ip`))
             ";
mysql_query($statement);
```

This will perform a multi-insert (far more efficient than individual queries), and when you try to insert the same ID twice it will instead concatenate the values.

It should be noted that this is bad database design, though :p

Comment: i have tried it.at the top i added $ip_details=$_POST['ip'];then placing $ip_details in $values=array($ip_detals).after concat(`column_ name`,',',??)";placing $to_insert is giving "Notice: Array to string conversion"